# how to put a semi circle on integral sign in mathmode?

Tags: math-mode, integral

I want to make a semicircle on integral sign like \ointclockwise for path integral.  hope you can help.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this might help?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{esint}% for \ointclockwise
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}
\newcommand\semiInt[1][1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
        \coordinate (center) at (1.1,0.55);
        \draw[black,-{>[scale=0.6]}] (0, 0.0) + (center) arc (0:-180:0.5);
        \draw (0.1,0.55) --(1.1,0.55);
       $\int$
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\begin{document}
    \noindent
    The result is: \semiInt \\
    \verb|\ointclockwise| is: $\ointclockwise$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel,graphicx,amssymb,amsmath,wasysym}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\intsemicircle}{%
  \ThisStyle{\mathop{\ensurestackMath{\stackinset{c}{-0.4\LMpt}{c}{.1pt}{%
  \rotatebox[origin=lb]{-90}{$\SavedStyle\Rightcircle$}}{\SavedStyle\int}}}}}

\begin{document}

$\displaystyle\intsemicircle_0^\infty$

\end{document}
```

[image]